Use composition OOP design principle to refactor a legacy application code
I'm working on the code for an old application for which it is not possible to modify the database tables under any circumstances. It is therefore not possible to add the Characteristics fields to the "Residence.java" class and the "Residences" table.
In fact, more than 20 characteristics properties are declared in all the child classes, i.e. "Apartment.java", "House.java" and "Farm.java" and their corresponding tables too i.e "Apartments table", "Houses table" and "Farms table".
My question: How can I use composition to group and externalise the common properties without changing the database tables, at the same time I want to access the Characteristic object from the Residence parent object.
@Embeddable
Class Characteristic {
   // For brievety other properties are not included
   private String characteristic01;
             ...
   private String characteristic20;
}

@Enity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "DTYPE", columnDefinition = "SMALLINT", discriminatorType = 
DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
Class Abstract Residence {
     // For brievety other properties are not included
     @Transient
     Characteristic characteristic;
     ...
     // Setters & Getters
}

@Entity
Class Appartement extend Residence {
    // For brievety other properties are not included  
    @Embedded
    private Characteristic characteristic;
}

@Entity
Class House extend Residence  {
    // For brievety other properties are not included
    @Embedded
    private Characteristic characteristic;
}

@Entity
Class Farm extend Residence  {
    // For brievety other properties are not included
    @Embedded
    private Characteristic characteristic;
}

